# How to makes a Rich ToolTip in JSF visible or not visible?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

i have a question concerning rich:toolTip component. I have the following jsf code:

```
<rich:toolTip followMouse="true" >
    <h:outputText value="#{messages.dto.Station}" escape="false" converter="bbCodeConverter" />
</rich:toolTip>
```

This ToolTip works grateful, but it will be sign a empty tooltip, if messages.dto.Station is empty too. How can i solve this problem in that way, that the tooltip is not visible, if messages.dto.Station is empty?

Thanks for helping me !

Greetz
Marwief

Comment: try rendered="#{not empty messages.dto.Station}"

Answer (score 3):

```
<rich:toolTip followMouse="true" 
  rendered="#{messages.dto.Station !=null or messages.dto.Station !=''}" >
  <h:outputText value="#{messages.dto.Station}" 
    escape="false" converter="bbCodeConverter"/>
 </rich:toolTip>
```

Using the rendered attribute will help you to only show when your #{messages.dto.Station} is not empty  [rich faces doc link](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/toolTip.jsf?tab=info&cid=469247)

Comment: rendered="#{messages.dto.Station !=null or messages.dto.Station !=""}" > Is here a syntax error included? The part ""}" make some problems in my editor. I work with jsf 1.2

Comment: Do you have a solution for jsf 1.2 ?

Comment: Then you have to create a boolean attribute in your managed bean and check for the condition in the behaviour for the managed bean

Comment: <rich:toolTip followMouse="true" 
  rendered="#{checkForToolTip}" >
  <h:outputText value="#{messages.dto.Station}" 
    escape="false" converter="bbCodeConverter"/>
 </rich:toolTip>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38973/discussion-between-bholavishwakarma-and-marwief)

Answer (score 0):

In JSF 1.2 you can use the `rendered` attribute as @BholaVishwakarma has described.

That should work on JSF 1.2 also

Here is a free tip for you.
You should avoid using uppercase letters on beans. `messages.dto.Station`. 
It should be `messages.dto.station`

Try the following

```
<rich:toolTip followMouse="true" 
  rendered="#{messages.dto.Station !=null and not empty messages.dto.Station}">
...
```